# Remove TinyMCE Toolbar Button

Tags: tinymce

How do I remove a button from the TinyMCE toolbar?

Do I directly edit the tiny_mce.js file? If so, where? Do I edit my theme's editor_template.js file?

Any instruction or hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define exactly what you want on the toolbar with the advanced theme and you wind up just specifying a list of buttons.  See http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration for the configuration reference or the examples at http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/full.php

Answer (score 2):

In case you need to remove button dynamically, you can use following technique:

```
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        toolbar: "custom",
        formats: {custom: {inline: "span", styles: {color: "red"}}},
        setup: function(editor){

            editor.addCustomButton = function () {
               if(this.customButton){
                   this.customButton.show();
               } else {
                   this.addButton("custom", {
                       onpostrender: function() {
                           editor.customButton = this; //saving button reference
                       }
                   });
               }
            };

            editor.removeCustomButton = function () { this.customButton.hide(); };
        }
    });
```

Now you can call editor's methods `addCustomButton` and `removeCustomButton` from wherever you need.