# Tinymce how to remove displayed features in editor?

Tags: tinymce

How do I remove the disabled features in Tinymce editor. I dont want them to appear.
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove TinyMCE Toolbar Button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737440/remove-tinymce-toolbar-button)

Comment: I found the solution, I did have duplicate options of Tiny mce. I removed one of my tiny mce configurations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed one of my tiny mce configurations